# Before AVRDude?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, avrdude

I was just wondering and decided to have a look but I couldn't find anything...

What was the process that you had to do or tools you had to use before AVRDude came about, because from what I can tell AVRDude is a private tool made by Brian S. Dean which became so popular its now the defacto in programming your AVR.

But since its not an official AVR tool by ATMEL what did you have to do before AVRdude came about? Its not that I don't want to use it, its just im curious. A bit like the chicken and the egg..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/start_now.aspx

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick that's almost an answer.

Comment: @Phil: hint taken :-)

Answer (score 1):

Atmel provide a set of software development tools for their AVR microcontrollers. The current product is  [Atmel Studio 6](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/start_now.aspx). This includes the ability to load compiled software into a microcontroller's flash memory using Atmel "programmer" hardware.

Generally, the designers or manufacturers of microcontroller and/or microprocessor systems provide a tool set to encourage engineers to use their products. Sometimes they charge for these software tools but often they are provided for free.

I'm not sure of the motivation for the development of avrdude but I guess it is likely to have included one or more of the following:

- Atmel tools are proprietary, some people prefer open-source.

  - lack ability to use third party programming hardware?
  - lacked ability to use some alternative compilers / development languages?
- Probably Atmel tools didn't run on all development platforms (e.g. FreeBSD, Linux?).

It is likely that Atmel have subsequently addressed some of the reasons for the development of avrdude, for example Atmel Studio 6 has some support for the GCC compiler chain.

Comment: I think your reply focuses more to the current development tools and possible reasons why avrdude was created (by the way here is a [history](http://www.cs.vassar.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?%28avrdude%29History) link) but that doesn't answer to `what was the process that you had to do or tools you had to use before AVRDude`